# How do Bootstrap Glyphicons work?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I know some basics of CSS and HTML and sometimes work with them, but am not a professional, and I'm curious about how Bootstrap Glyphicons work. I mean there are no images in the Bootstrap zip file, so where do the images come from?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

In Bootstrap 2.x, Glyphicons used the image method - using images as you mentioned in your question.

The drawbacks with the image method was that:

- You couldn't change the color of the icons
- You couldn't change the background-color of the icons
- You couldn't increase the size of the icons

So instead of glyphicons in Bootstrap 2.x, a lot of people used Font-awesome, as this used SVG icons which did not have such limitations.

In Bootstrap 3.x, Glyphicons use the font method.

Using a font to represent an icon has advantages over using images:

- Scalable - works nicely regardless of client device's resolution
- Can change the colour with CSS
- Can do everything traditional icons can (e.g. change opacity, rotation, etc.)
- Can add strokes, gradients, shadows, and etc.
- Convert to text (with ligatures)
- Ligatures are read by screen readers
- Changing icons to fonts is as simple as changing the font-family in CSS

You can see what you can do with the font method for icons [here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/).

So in the Bootstrap distribution, you can see the glyphicon font files:

```
fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

The Bootstrap CSS refers to the glyphicon font like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

And the CSS links to this font using the `.glyphicon` base class (note the `font-family`):

```
.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  ...
}
```

And then each glyphicon uses an individual icon class which refers to a [Unicode reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font) within the Glyphicon Halflings font, e.g.:

```
.glyphicon-envelope:before {
  content: "\2709";
}
```

This is why you must use the base `.glyphicon` class as well as the individual icon class against the `span` element in Bootstrap 3:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks, @mccannf, for such detailed explanation. Btw, the css-tricks.com is cool! Thank you.

Comment: I believe that the link to a Unicode font for a Unicode reference is incorrect, a Unicode font is something entirely different. You probably want something like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/string), or [this](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes)?