# How to get glyphicons working in twitter-bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I've got bootstrap files stored locally:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and

```
<script src="/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

but when I do this:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

I get a little square character such as is displayed when the client doesn't have the proper font. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205738/how-to-use-glyphicons-in-bootstrap-3-0) that there's separate CSS, but the link is broken. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Glyphicons are included in the default bootstrap.min.css – make sure you're not using plugins, such as NoScript, which might block loading of external font files

Comment: @knittl, do I have to download font files also? I've got the files stored locally.

Comment: @JonathanM Yes, you need to download the font files as well.

Comment: hope you are not including necessary font

Comment: @imaphpdeveloper, can you explain. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by your comment.

Comment: @JonathanM: yes, you need the files locally. Your original question used the css from maxcdn, which would know where to find the required font files.

Comment: @JonathanM what I mean, if you use bootsstrap you will have fonts folder and inside you can find glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot etc.. That may not be included I said

Comment: you can refer this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279512/how-do-bootstrap-glyphicons-work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it:

Needed to locally create:

```
/bootstrap/3.2.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
/bootstrap/3.2.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
/bootstrap/3.2.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
/bootstrap/3.2.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
```

which I sourced from here:

http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg

Comment: If you go to http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download and press `Download Bootstrap` it will come with a folder that has `css, fonts, js`. You shouldn't have to download each from the CDN, seems a bit backwards to me.

Comment: @Tim, yeah, I think I just ignored the /fonts folder when I originally downloaded. I definitely went about it backwards.

Comment: It's easy enough to miss. I was familiar with Font Awesome before I knew about glyphicons, so I knew they were technically a font, but I can see how it could be overlooked. Glad you got it working though!

Answer (score 1):

There is Jonathan, inside the bootstrap download you should have the following file structure (unless you selected NOT to download glyphicons as a component)

**css ->** bootstrap.css, bootstrap.css.map, bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap-theme.css, bootstrap-theme.css.map, bootstrap-theme.min.css

**fonts ->** glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot, glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg, glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf, glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff, glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

**js ->** bootstrap.js, bootstrap.min.js, npm.js

If you dont have that, i'd recommend going to http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download and downloading the package.  Linking it up inside your own folder is easy.  Just rename the Bootstrap CSS folder to 'Bootstrap' then drag it to your CSS folder in your file (you can take the files directly, but having the folder as *CSS/Bootstrap/bootstrapCSSfiles* it just makes it more organized.  Do that again for JS and Fonts and you're all set.

Goodluck bud :D

Answer (score -2):

It works with no problems.

`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span>`

http://jsfiddle.net/3v1tyL61/

Comment: Sorry, I posted wrong info. Revised the question. I've got the bs files stored locally. Is there a font folder I should also have?

Comment: @MacKentoch, do I need to download the font?

Comment: Ah, I think I found it. I was missing: /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot    Downloaded the original from here: http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot